# Runtime avoiding asInstanceOf

Tags: scala, types

Here is a simplified version of a design that is trying to compose function in runtime. So the `pipelineS` comes in the runtime (in form of json or something) and the traverse executes it. Also, we know that the runtime input WILL be a valid composition(functions in/out types matches).

I want to define the functions that have type information and avoid `asInstanceOF`.

One partial solution I see is [Here](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/is-it-possible-to-store-and-retreive-function-definitions-for-later-composition/2394) but it's very complicated and it's hard to expand to different size of input arguments.

```scala
abstract class Func extends Product {
  val meta:FuncMeta
}

case class FuncMeta(name:String, outType:String, inTypes:List[String])
case class Fun0(meta:FuncMeta, run:() => Any) extends Func
case class Fun1(meta:FuncMeta, run:Any => Any) extends Func
case class Fun2(meta:FuncMeta, run:(Any, Any) => Any) extends Func

val literal2 = Fun0(FuncMeta("literal2", "int", List.empty), () => 2)
val literal10 = Fun0(FuncMeta("literal10", "int", List.empty), () => 10)
val twice = Fun1(FuncMeta("twice", "int", "int" :: Nil) ,(a:Any) => a.asInstanceOf[Int] * 2)
val larger = Fun2(FuncMeta("larger", "bool", "int" :: "int" :: Nil) ,(a:Any, b:Any) => a.asInstanceOf[Int] > b.asInstanceOf[Int])
val add = Fun2(FuncMeta("add", "int", "int" :: Nil), (a:Any, b:Any) => a.asInstanceOf[Int] + b.asInstanceOf[Int])

//a Map[String, Func] for runtime access and retrieve of functions
//Basically this is the way the Functions are stored
val funcs = List(literal2, literal10, twice, larger, add).map(x => x.meta.name -> x).toMap

def traverse(tree: Treee[Func]):Any = {
  val t = tree.t
  val kids = tree.kids

  val rs = kids.map(k => traverse(k))
  t match {
    case Fun0(meta, run) => run()
    case Fun1(meta, run) => run(rs.head)
    case Fun2(meta, run) => run(rs(0), rs(1))
  }
}

//RUNTIME information
//can be a userinput Json that gets converted to the following by accessing the funcs Map
val pipelineS = Treee[Func](
    funcs("larger"),
    List(
        Treee(funcs("literal10")),
        Treee(funcs("literal2"))
      )
  )

println(traverse(pipelineS))
```

Comment: Can you share how would you expect to use this? Like what should your users see, what will their inputs look like. And how do you expect them to use this functionality.

Comment: The usage is at the bottom of the code: e.g. traverse

Comment: I mean, you really want your users to create all those **Funs** and **Trees**? Given that, why wont the use normal scala functions. I was supposing that your users would pass some kind of String representing their plan and you would parse that.

Comment: Yes, imagine it's json that someone in frontend creates the tree and send it to backend to be executed.

Comment: So, are all the functions ones you define ahead of time and the user accesses by name? Or is the user creating their own functions?

Comment: @Ethan for simplicity let's assume the functions are defined at compile time (e.g add, larger and ...). TBH, in the future, I want to have the users to define functions at runtime by composing existing function and giving them names.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create a typed encoding like this one:

```
sealed trait Term {
  type T
  def run(): T
}

object Term {
  type Aux[_T] = Term { type T = _T }
}

final case class Lit[A] (value: A) extends Term {
  override final type T = A
  override final def run(): T = value
}

final case class Tuple[A, B](a: Term.Aux[A], b: Term.Aux[B]) extends Term {
  override final type T = (A, B)
  override final def run(): T = (a.run(), b.run())
}

final case class Fun[I, O](input: Term.Aux[I])(f: I => O) extends Term {
  override final type T = O
  override final def run(): T = f(input.run())
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
val expr: Term = Fun(Tuple(Lit(2), Fun(Lit(3))(_ * 5))) {
  case (a, b) => a + b
}

expr.run()
// res: Term.T = 17
```

The problem would be how to create such expression from your user input.

Comment: AS I mentioned in the comments and the descriptions the input is in runtime, that's why we have a Map[String,Fun] to give an example of how they might be retrieved.

Comment: @Omid that is why I asked how was the raw input. If you can parse it to a function like `() => 2` you can create a types object like the ones I posted.

Comment: Here is a good exercise to see if it's possible or not, try all the functions into a Map[String,Term] and retrieve them by name, like the example I've given. The link that I have in the description is a good read.

Comment: @Omid you may use **type members** instead _(I edited the answer)_. But when you create the `Map` you will lose all the type information. You may only call `run()` on it, but you would not know which is the output type. It is still unclear to me what are the inputs and how do you expect to use the results.

Comment: If you look at my example, you'll see that I have defined the functions beforehand (e.g. larger, add, ...) and store in a Map and then in runtime I retrieved it by name and used it. Your example is not doing that. Please see if you can reproduce the runtime part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is an easy solutions if you want to avoid type casts during function execution.

If I really had to do it I'd start like that:

1) Start with functions of one argument. `FunctionMeta[I, O]` must be typed with the input type and the output type. Type casts would happen when you parse your json into `FunctionMeta[I, O]`, not when you run it.

2) Use type-aligned data structures to store the sequence of functions as proposed in the discussion you linked.

3) After you make functions of 1 argument work - model functions of multiple arguments as functions from `HList`.